# Enviar emails com HTML/CSS embutido CakePhp

Tags: cakephp, envio-de-email

Boa tarde!

Estou tentando fazer uma coisa "simples", preciso enviar um email estilizado, não quero enviar apenas texto, preciso inserir tags html e css.
Antes de trabalhar com cakePHP eu usava o `PHPmailler`, no qual eu conseguia enviar emails com `HTML` e `CSS` in line.

Estou trabalhando em um projeto que utiliza o framework cakePHP.
Na documentação, me parece que ele tem a possibiliade de enviar emails com o css embutido, da mesma forma que eu fazia, mas todos os emails enviados vão com as tags HTML printadas como se fossem textos simples.

```
$email = new CakeEmail('smtp');
$email->template('contato');    
$email->emailFormat('html');        
$email->to('****************');
$email->subject('Contato - Fale Conosco');
$email->viewVars(array('contato' => $this->request->data));
$email->send();
```

Esse é o código que estou utiliando para enviar os emails e a view é:

```
<html>
<body>
    <p><strong>Contato Recebido</strong></p>

    <p>Data: <strong><?php echo date("d/m/Y"); ?></strong></p>
    <p>Nome: <strong><?php echo $contato['Contato']['nome']?></strong></p>
    <p>Telefone: <strong><?php echo $contato['Contato']['telefone']?></strong></p>
    <p>E-mail: <strong><?php echo $contato['Contato']['email']?></strong></p>
    <p>Assunto: <strong><?php echo $contato['Contato']['assunto']?></strong></p>
    <p>Mensagem: <strong><?php echo $contato['Contato']['mensagem']?></strong></p>
</body>
```

Porém, quando eu deixo o parâmetro "$email->emailFormat('html');" as mensagens enviadas chegam em branco, quando eu removo esse parâmetro deixando o default(text) as mensagem chegam com o html na tela como se fosse texto simples e se eu colocar o parâmetro como "both" não chega nada.

Comment: 1º o CSS que deseja aplicar pode estar `inline` ou quer uma folha de estilo mesmo? 2º Obrigatoriamente o Email tem de passar pelo servidor?

Comment: @RicardoHenrique

O css está inline(na verdade ainda não está nem inline, queria resolver essas tags html que estão expostas no email,)  e o email não precisa passar pelo servidor.

Comment: trabalhei com algo assim, Julgo ter uma solução então aguarde que irei postar.

Comment: @RicardoHenrique Ok, estou no aguardo.

Answer (score 1):

1º Utilizei o MandrilJS que é um serviço que me envia 12 Mil emails de forma gratuita pra você (isso não é spam). funciona como meio de campo para não precisar de um servidor.

Link para acesso (é necessário criar uma conta): [MandrilJS](https://www.mandrill.com/)

2º Crie um formulário comum e (coloque como `method` `POST` só pra não encher a URL mas nada será enviado para um servidor) no botão de envio faça-o desta forma:

```
<button onClick="sendMail();return false;">Enviar</button>
```

3º Crie um `Javascript` com uma função de mesmo nome que a do botão que irá recuperar os campos preenchidos pelo usuário do formulário:

```
function sendMail(){
    var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var assunto = document.getElementById("assunto").value;
    var desc = document.getElementById("desc").value;
    var body = '<strong>Nome: </strong>'+nome+'<br />'+
               '<strong>Email: </strong>'+email+'<br />'+
               '<strong>Assunto: </strong>'+assunto+'<br />'+
               '<strong>Descição: </strong>'+desc;

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json",
        data:{
                'key':'sua chave aqui',
                'message':{
                    'from_email':'email que irá enviar',
                    'to':[
                        {
                            'email':'email remetente',
                            'name':'Seu Nome (ou nick)',
                            'type':'to'
                        }
                    ],
                    'subject':'Assunto',
                    'html':body
                }
            }
    });
}
```

**OBS1:** Não é necessário inserir suas senhas de email em local algum, você deverá somente se cadastrar no `MandrilJS` (sem inserir senha de seus emails) e gerar uma chave, chave esta que será inserida no json no local especifico (ela é gerado nas configurações).

**OBS2:** É necessário jQuery.

**OBS3:** Pode inserir o CSS nas tags

**OBS4:** Ambos os Emails tem de ser validos o Destinatário por rasões obvias ele irá receber os emails, o Remente por que o MandriJS envia semanalmente as estatísticas de envios e leituras dos email.

Comment: Comente aqui qualquer duvida no processo de criação de sua conta.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Ricardo, é uma solução.
Mas eu preciso que seja enviado do back-end, de preferencia de forma nativa com o cake. 
Nesse caso que postei é de um simples formulário de contato, mas existem outros trechos que enviam email no back-end...
Ainda estou pesquisando por possíveis soluções, talvez eu utilize sua reposta para elaborar um curl e enviar o email!

Obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: OK, espero que encontre uma solução, se encontrar poste Aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite,
Consegui encontrar uma solução para o meu problema.

Primeira coisa que tive que fazer foi remover as tags de abertura do HTML, mas não tenho certeza se foi isso que resolveu.
Segunda coisa que reparei, na minha pasta /app/Views/Emails/html, eu não tinha o template "contato", por esse motivo meus emails html iam sempre vazios e os emails do tipo text não.
Creio que foram as únicas modificações que fiz.

Obrigado pela ajuda!